# Unable to fetch the value from UITableViewCell by the self define methods

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uitableview

I am creating an app in which i have a UITableView and the table view each cell are having an UIView and the UIView contains two custom UIButton and two UILabel(all with same tag) the value of label coming from XML parsing. Now i have to do is that when i click any one button then it calls a method with the tag of the button then i want to fetch the value of the both labels of that cell and use that value.

But when i am doing this it is not happen by calling a method i am getting the tag value but when i try to get the label value then i am unable to get.

Is there any way to get the value of that?

Code of the method that i am using to get the label value...

```
-(void)swapButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    NSInteger a= [sender tag];

    UITableViewCell *cell; 
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *) [[sender superview] superview]];
    NSLog(@"%d", indexPath.row);

    UIView *viewForCell = (UIView *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:a];

    UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[viewForCell viewWithTag:a];
    NSString *str = label.text;
}
```

Code of the method cellForRowAtIndexPath....

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1 cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    static NSString *identifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:identifier];
    if (cell == nil) {
        cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:identifier] autorelease];
    }
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
    NSDictionary *dict = [appDelegate.webDataList objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.39 green:0.39 blue:0.39 alpha:0.39];

    if([appDelegate.dataArray count]>0){

        imgView.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        imgView =[[UIView alloc ] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,320,45)];
        imgView.tag= indexPath.row;
        [cell.contentView addSubview:imgView];

        button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(291, 5, 19, 21);
        img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"swap_re" ofType:@"png"]];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(swapButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag= indexPath.row;
        [imgView addSubview:button];

        button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(-25, 5, 19, 21);
        img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"swap_re" ofType:@"png"]];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(swapButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        button.tag= indexPath.row;
        [imgView addSubview:button];

        button=[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame=CGRectMake(5, 7, 19, 21);
        button.tag = indexPath.row;
        img =[UIImage imageWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"delete" ofType:@"png"]];
        [button setBackgroundImage:img forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(deleteButtonPressed:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];    
        [imgView addSubview:button];

        NSArray *arr = [[appDelegate.dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] componentsSeparatedByString:@"/"];


        UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(34,9,140,20)];
        label.text = [arr objectAtIndex:1];
        label.tag = indexPath.row;
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:14]];
        [label setNumberOfLines:0];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        label.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        label.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
        [imgView addSubview:label];
        [label release];


        label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(181, 7, 75, 20)];
        label.tag = indexPath.row;
        label.text = [dict1 objectForKey:@"time"];
        [label setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Georgia" size:16.0]];
        label.textAlignment = UITextAlignmentLeft;
        [label setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        label.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleLeftMargin | UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleHeight;
        [label setTextColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        [imgView addSubview:label];
        [label release];
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Comment: How do you set your label text, could post the `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method also?

Comment: can you give cellForIndex... method code ?

Comment: I have add that method code you can check

Comment: in the code imgView is UIView type

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two problems:

1. Tags need to be > 0 so you can't use `indexPath.row` directly.
2. Tags need to be unique within a superview

As @Kenny suggests, getting the `indexPath` from the cell and accessing the data source directly is generally more reliable. If you want to get values from the objects in the cell use unique tags > 0. I usually define an enum for tags within a subview to make things more readable.

Comment: if i define indexpath as tag then the array can not get the values because it goes out of bounds....not in integer

Comment: The requirements of the tag parameter are as I stated. I never said to use "indexPath as tag", not sure what you mean by that.

Answer (score 0):

I think that viewWithTag is recursive, so in your code that would mean that you get the label back in the first call to it, and nil in the second call. So perhaps this would work:

```
UILabel *label = (UILabel *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:a];
NSString *str = label.text;
```

However, I'd recommend you get the value from your model object where you probably got it when you set the string on the button in the first place, something like this:

```
NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForCell:(UITableViewCell *) [[sender superview] superview]];
TheObect *obj = [myobjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
NSString *string = obj.name;
```